# How to type-hint generic as a parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I‘ve created a simple `Form` class in TypeScript:

```ts
class Form<FormData> {
    protected data: FormData;

    constructor(data: FormData) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I’ve added the type parameter so that I can type the data the form should receive when instantiating this class. For example:

```ts
interface UpdateUserForm {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

const updateUserForm = new Form<UpdateUserForm>;
```

However, I’m having a problem when trying to use my `Form` class as an argument of other classes, because it’s expecting the type. So, given a method like this:

```ts
class Http {
    post(url: string, form: Form) {
        return axios(url, form.data);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Generic type 'Form' requires 1 type argument(s).

However, I don’t *know* the `FormData` type in this method with it being generic.

How would I go about type-hinting this `form` parameter properly?

Comment: Make the _method_ generic, so it can be e.g. `Form<T>`? See examples in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html.

Comment: Thanks. Would that not mean I’d then need to constantly specify the type when invoking that `post` method though, i.e. `post<UpdateUserForm>(url, form)`? I’m just wanting to pass a `Form` instance, but not worry about its type.

Comment: @MartinBean - No, TypeScript can infer it from the actual form argument you supply to the function at the call site. For instance, if the form you're calling `post` with has the type `Form<NiftyData>`, the call is just `post("/path/to/whatever", theForm)`, no need for the type argument on the call.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, misread it a bit. Martin, I meant `post<FormDataType>(url: string, Form<FormDataType>)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, this seems to work. Can you add your comment as an answer? Then I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said in the comments, you can make the *method* generic, like this:

```typescript
post<FormDataType>(url: string, form: Form<FormDataType>) {
    // ...
}
```

When you're calling it, TypeScript will infer the type argument based on the type of the `Form` you pass to it. For instance, if you have:

```typescript
const niftyForm = new Form<NiftyData>(/*...*/);
// ...
http.post("/some/url", niftyForm);
```

...TypeScript will infer `NiftyData` for the type argument for `post` from the type of `niftyForm` (which is `Form<NiftyData>`). (You *can* provide it explicitly as well, but there's no need with this `post` method. Explicit type arguments are needed when they can't be inferred, for instance if they drive the return type of a method that can't otherwise fully specify what it's returning because it's too dynamic.)

There are more examples in [the handbook's section on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).